# Setting the headers of a dataframe as the top row of a .csv export

Tags: python, pandas

I would like the top row of the excel file to be the headers of the dataframe. (`header=0` does this)

When the dataframe is saved as a .csv, I would like the headers to be on row 1 of the .csv, just as they were in the original .csv (this is what I am having trouble achieving)

I have tried setting the `header=` of `.to_csv` to both None or 0, but neither cause the headers to become row 1 of the `.to_csv` file.

I am now trying to set row 0 as a df1 and concatenate it with df, but am getting a 'first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "Series"'

Can anyone offer any insight about how to approach this, or if there is an easier way?

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\dusti\Desktop\bulk export.xlsx',
                       sheet_name=0,
                       header=0)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df1 = df. loc[0, :]

df = pd.concat(df1, df)

df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\dusti\Desktop\bulk export1.xlsx',
          header=None,
          index=False)
```

Comment: You're conflating Excel and CSV. Excel is not CSV, and just so happens to be able to work with CSV files (rather poorly in my opinion). If you need an Excel file, then use `to_excel` instead of `to_csv`.

Comment: thank you - I just made this change but am still running into the same error

Comment: Remove `df1 = df. loc[0, :]` and `df = pd.concat(df1, df)` and `header=None`, and use `startrow=1`.

Comment: Thank you. This is causing the export .xlsx file to have a blank first row, and still has no headings.

Comment: Sry misread the question, thought you wanted the headers in the second row not first. Just use `df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\dusti\Desktop\bulk export1.xlsx', index=False)` or `df.to_csv` as you originally had, and the headers will be in the first row.

Comment: Did this work for you, @anarchocaps?

Comment: (Please show us your dataframe header row and index, e.g. post `df.head(4)` as text. Is your index a multiindex?)

Comment: Side note: `data = pd.read_excel(...)`: `data` is already a `DataFrame` so drop `df = pd.DataFrame(data)`

Comment: adding header=True to the export function solved it, along with deleting the header= argument. thank you

Answer (score 0):

(Please show us your dataframe header row and index, e.g. post `df.head(4)` as text. We need to see your index).

Possible issues:

1. pandas [`.to_excel()` and `to_csv()` `header`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) argument expects *True (bool) or else a list of string column names*.

This is different behavior than [`read_csv(header)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) which can also take an int (*row number(s) to use as the column names*).

But you're trying to pass the int `header=0` into `to_excel()/to_csv()`

2. If your index is a multiindex (is it?) and you use option `to_excel(..., index=False)`, pandas has an ongoing open known issue
   [Export to excel for multiindex columns #11292](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11292). Solutions: a) use `index=True` or else b) don't create a multindex on your dataframe, or c) `unstack()` your multiindex.